# Function with character pointer as arguments

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code when the function print_uart transfer the string "Hello world" whats exactly received in *s?Is it the character H or the address of the memory where the string "Hello World" is stored??

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;
void print_uart0(const char *s)
{
  while(*s != '\0')  
  {                                 /* Loop until end of string */
    *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s);  /* Transmit char */
    s++;                            /* Next char */
  }
}
void c_entry() 
{
    print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
}
```

Comment: `volatile unsigned int * const` - What does this mean being constant and volatile

Comment: `s` is a pointer, `*s` is char value. `*UAT0DR = (...)(*s)` uses value.

Comment: @Ed, the pointer is `const`, the thing it points to is `volatile`.

Comment: @chux - Did not think this thru. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is a pointer to the memory where the string "Hello World" is stored.
`*s` is the first character, `'H'`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler takes all your string constants and allocate memory for them. In `s` you have a place in memory where it is stored and by `*s` you get first character of this string.

It is also important to note that using exactly same string constants would probably point to the same place in memory -> such optimization saves some memory.

Answer (score 0):

The argument s points to the first character of the string literal "Hello world!\n". A string is by default terminated with \0
so the while loop

```
while(*s != '\0')  
{                                 /* Loop until end of string */
  *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s);  /* Transmit char */
  s++;                            /* Next char */
}
```

copies one character at a time H,e,... to the same address 'UART0DR'